# App crashing at the end of array

Tags: android, arrays

My app is crashing at the end of the array in bluestacks. I have no idea why.

When I click the next button at the end of the array, the app crashes. I also tested it on my phone, same result. The rest of the app functions as intended.

From what I know "i %= image_elements.length;" is supposed to be the function that loops the array.

I am pretty sure this is where the crash is coming from.

```
i++;

element.setImageResource(image_elements[i]);
name.setImageResource(image_names[i]);

i %= image_elements.length;
```

Full code below

```
public class Practice extends MainMenuActivity {

    int i = 0;
    final int[] image_elements = {
        R.drawable.spr_elements_0,
        R.drawable.spr_elements_1,
        [...]
        R.drawable.spr_elements_86,
        R.drawable.spr_elements_87,
    };
    final int[] image_names = {
        R.drawable.spr_name_0,
        R.drawable.spr_name_1,
        [...]
        R.drawable.spr_name_86,
        R.drawable.spr_name_87,
    };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.practice);

            final ImageView element = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.element);
            final ImageView name = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.name);

            Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
            nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            i++;

                            element.setImageResource(image_elements[i]);
                            name.setImageResource(image_names[i]);

                            i %= image_elements.length;
                    }
            });
    }
    public void backButton(View view) {
            Intent z = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to rearrange your code from this:

```
                        i++;

                        element.setImageResource(image_elements[i]);
                        name.setImageResource(image_names[i]);

                        i %= image_elements.length;
```

to this:

```
                        i++;
                        i %= image_elements.length;

                        element.setImageResource(image_elements[i]);
                        name.setImageResource(image_names[i]);
```

What happens otherwise is that the index is incremented beyond the boundaries of the array, and that is corrected afterwards with the modulus operator. You'll need to the the correction *before* you use the index.

`i %= image_elements.length` in this particular case, is essentially the same as

```
if( i == image_elements.length ) {
    i = 0;
}
```

Arrays indices go from `0` to `length-1`.

You could get rid of the arrays entirely by looking up the resources by name, such as this:

```
final static int MAX_ELEMENTS = 88; // this includes 0..87
private int index = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.practice);

        final ImageView element = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.element);
        final ImageView name = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        final Resources res = this.getResources();
        final String pkgName = this.getPackageName();

        Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        final int imgId = res.getIdentifier( "spr_elements_" + index, "drawable", pkgName );
                        final int nameId = res.getIdentifier( "spr_name_" + index, "drawable", pkgName );
                        element.setImageResource( imgId );
                        name.setImageResource( nameId );

                        index = (index+1) % MAX_ELEMENTS;
                }
        });
}
```

Comment: I am trying to loop is backwards on a if statement, but it crashes at the end. Here is my statement:

            Button prevButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrev);
            prevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        i = 87;
                    } else {
                        i--;
                    }
                    element.setImageResource(image_elements[i]);
                    name.setImageResource(image_names[i]);
                }
            });

Comment: What is the value of `i` when it crashes? What is the crash?

Comment: Thank you, it would drop to -1 one. So I just put it as if (i==0) {//do nothing} else {i--}
Thank you all for your help